# Capture a list of integers in a string using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture `List[int]` (list of integers which might be seperated by a comma) in a string. However I am not getting the expected result.

```py
>>> txt = '''Automatic face localisation is the prerequisite step of 
facial image analysis for many applications such as facial attribute 
(e.g. expression [64] and age [38]) and facial identity
recognition [45, 31, 55, 11]. A narrow deﬁnition of face localisation 
may refer to traditional face detection [53, 62], '''
```

output

```py
>>> re.findall(r'[(\b\d{1,3}\b,)+]',txt)
['(', '6', '4', '3', '8', ')', '4', '5', ',', '3', '1', ',', '5', '5', ',', '1', '1', '5', '3', ',', '6', '2', ',']
```

What should be the expression to capture the below output.

Expected output:

```
['[64]', '[38]', '[45, 31, 55, 11]', '[53, 62]']
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
\[[\d, ]*?]
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

[image: Pictorial Representation]

Please find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/GmymA6/16)

**Sample Implementation in python**

```
import re

regex = r"\[[\d, ]*?]"

test_str = ("Automatic face localisation is the prerequisite step of facial image analysis for many applications such as facial attribute (e.g. expression [64] and age [38]) and facial identity\n"
    "... recognition [45, 31, 55, 11]. A narrow deﬁnition of face localisation may refer to traditional face detection [53, 62]")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
# Outputs: ['[64]', '[38]', '[45, 31, 55, 11]', '[53, 62]']
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/Byw-8KXJP)

Answer (score 2):

You can match 1-3 digits. Then repeat 0+ times matching a comma, 0+ spaces and again 1-3 digits.

```
\[\d{1,3}(?:, *\d{1,3})*]
```

- `\[` Match `{`
- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `, *\d{1,3}`
- `)*` Close the group and repeat it 0+ times
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PFMA1V/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Jl1qNI)

*Example*

```
import re

txt = '''Automatic face localisation is the prerequisite step of facial image analysis for many applications such as facial attribute (e.g. expression [64] and age [38]) and facial identity
... recognition [45, 31, 55, 11]. A narrow deﬁnition of face localisation may refer to traditional face detection [53, 62],
... '''

print (re.findall(r'\[\d{1,3}(?:, *\d{1,3})*]',txt))
```

*Output*

```
['[64]', '[38]', '[45, 31, 55, 11]', '[53, 62]']
```

---

If there can be more digits and spaces on all sides, including continuing the sequence on a newline:

```
\[\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4KQOa/1)